# Problem to display the good data (from a plist) in the right row in my sectioned tableview

Tags: ios, row, plist, tableview

I've a sectionned tableview with 3 sections (Motif - Couleur - Other)
The data of the tableview are loaded from a plist witch looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Root</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>DESCRIPTION</key>
            <string>Robe ponctuée de petites tâches sombres plus ou moins rondes et pleines tel que l&apos;on retrouve chez le guépard</string>
            <key>TITLE</key>
            <string>Spotted</string>
            <key>IMAGE</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>MINI</key>
            <string>spotted.png</string>
            <key>CAT</key>
            <string>MOTIFS</string>
        </dict>

        <dict>
            <key>DESCRIPTION</key>
            <string>La robe du bengal dit &quot;Brown&quot; est d&apos;une infinie richesse. Loin de se limiter ou brun, elle passe également par des tons de roux vifs de blonds dorés . Les yeux sont jaunes dorés ou verts. Bien connu du public, les bengals bruns sont toujours aussi populaires et recherchés.</string>
            <key>TITLE</key>
            <string>Brown</string>
            <key>IMAGE</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>MINI</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>CAT</key>
            <string>COULEURS</string>
        </dict>
```

the name of the section is store in my plist, but at the moment i don't know how to pick the name (CAT MOTIFS) in this plist and display it in the header of my sectionned tableview.
then a code it differently and it seens to work but the name of sections don't come from the plist.

that one of the problem that made me crasy

and the second one, the most important, in the first section i want to display 4 rows, 9 in the second section, and 3 in the third section.
the problem is that the app display a good sectioned tableview, with 3 sections well named, with the good number of row in each sections, but not the good data in the section
actualy the row one contain data 1-2-3-4, but the second row contain the data 1-2-3-4-5....
and what i what is to display the data 5-6-7....

i hope you understand what my problem is. 
Here is my rootviewcontroller.m

```
//
//  RootViewController.m
//  FichesRaces
//
//  Created by a3116b on 28/05/11.
//  Copyright 2011 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "CatsList.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@implementation RootViewController
@synthesize tabWebSites;







- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Charger le fichier .plist dans un tableau que l'on appelera  arrayFromFile
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cats" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *dictFromFile = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSArray *arrayFromFile = [dictFromFile objectForKey:@"Root"];

    // Créons un tableau temporaire que nous allons remplir avec un objet Website par NSDictionnary contenu dans le fichier .plist
    // Notez l'utilisation de NSEnumerator pour parcourir un tableau
    NSMutableArray *websitesToAdd = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSEnumerator *enumerator = [arrayFromFile objectEnumerator];
    NSDictionary *anObject;
    while ((anObject = [enumerator nextObject])) {
        CatsList *cl = [[CatsList alloc] initWithDictionaryFromPlist: anObject];
        [websitesToAdd addObject: cl];
        [cl release];
    }

    // Remplir la propriété tabWebSites avec le contenu du NSMutableArray précédent
    self.tabWebSites = [NSArray arrayWithArray:websitesToAdd];

    // Gestion de la mémoire : pour chaque alloc, n'oubliez pas le release qui va avec !
    [websitesToAdd release];
    [arrayFromFile release];
}




- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}



- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if ( section == 0 ) return @"Les Motifs";
    if ( section == 1 ) return @"Les Couleurs";
    if ( section == 2 ) return @"Bon à Savoir";

    return @"";

   // return [sectionHeaders objectAtIndex:section];
}






// Customize the number of sections in the table view.
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 3;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            return 4;
            break;

        case 1:
            return 13;
            break;

        default:
            return 3;
            break;
    }

   }







// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    if (indexPath.section == 2) {
        CellIdentifier = @"cell";
    }
//-----------------------------------------------

    NSUInteger sectionNumber = [indexPath section];
    NSUInteger rowNumber = [indexPath row];  

    // determine the correct row.
    // it will be restarted from 0 every time, and as
    // we're just loading in from one array, we need to
    // offset it by the right amount depending on the section.
    //  int sectionNumber = indexPath.row;
    if ( sectionNumber == 0 ) rowNumber = 4;
    if ( sectionNumber == 1 ) rowNumber = +5;
    if ( sectionNumber == 2 ) rowNumber = +18;


//-----------------------------------------------    

    // Les cellules sont mises en cache pour accélérer le traitement, sous l'identifiant "Cell",
    // on essaie récupère ce modèle de cellule s'il est déjà en cache
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Si on n'a pas réussi à sortir une cellule du cache, on crée un nouveau modèle de cellule
    // et on l'enregistre dans le cache
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }





    // On récupère l'objet Website qui correspon à la ligne que l'on souhaite afficher
    CatsList *cl = [self.tabWebSites objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // On configure la cellule avec le titre du site et sa description
    cell.textLabel.text = cl.TITLE;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = cl.DESCRIPTION;


    //important ajouter signalisation sinon APP REFUSE

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    // On renvoie la cellule configurée pour l'affichage
    return cell;
}



- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section == 3) {
        return nil;
    }
    return indexPath;
}





- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{



    DetailViewController *detailVC = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    detailVC.CL = [self.tabWebSites objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailVC animated:YES];
    [detailVC release];
}






- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Relinquish ownership any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];

    // Relinquish ownership of anything that can be recreated in viewDidLoad or on demand.
    // For example: self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

thanks for your very useful help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using a `rowNumber` variable to store an offset row index in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` but then you aren't doing anything with that amended value.

**Edit**

From what I can see maybe you should try this:

```
CatsList *cl = [self.tabWebSites objectAtIndex:rowNumber];
```